# SQL function for returning multiple XPath hits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table with a column which contains large XML documents. I want to get all the values of a particular attribute name (Surname), occurring at any point in any of the XML values.

Currently I have this query...

```
select distinct XmlCol.value('(//@Surname)[1]','varchar(200)') from (
    select * from MyTable
)
```

...it grabs the first occurrence of my desired attribute in each entry of the XML column, however as it only grabs the first, there may be any number of attributes appearing after that occurrence, in the same XML value.

The value() function only works with a single result, hence why I need to provide the [1] specifying return the first hit.

Is there a way to repeat this function to get all the hits in a piece of XML, or is there another function which takes an XPath and can return multiple values?

**Illustrated example**

In case above is not clear, a simple example would be if MyTable had a single XmlCol column, with just 2 rows.

Row 1

```
<SimpleXML>
   <ArbitraryElement Surname="Smith"/>
   <ArbitraryElement>
        <ArbitraryInnerElement Surname="Bauer"/>
   </ArbitraryElement>
</SimpleXML>
```

Row 2

```
<SimpleXML Surname="Bond">
</SimpleXML>
```

Note the attribute appears at different locations and in different elements, I want it to work with any amount of nested elements.

Currently my method only hits the first element per XML entry, so gives the output:

```
Smith, Bond
```

I'd like it to return an arbitrary amount per entry, meaning the result should be:

```
Smith, Bauer, Bond
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use a `CROSS APPLY` to achieve this.

```
select distinct XmlCol.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as [Value]
from MyTable
CROSS APPLY MyTable.XmlCol.nodes('(//@Surname)') as [Table]([Column])
```

Comment: The script was running for hours and never finished, might need to take a different approach... I'll accept this answer anyway.

Comment: Came back to this again as I'm looking at a similar issue now. Could you please expand on T(C). What do the letters stand for? Why are they needed?

Comment: Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type), the syntax for this is `nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column) `

Comment: Ah thanks very much! Hope you don't mind, i edited the answer for future clarity in case someone else sees this question

Comment: @dahui `Table`, `Column` and `Value` are [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) in SQL Server, therefore you have to use quoted identifiers. When you edit an answer please make sure, that it remains syntactically and semantically correct.